# How can set system preference programmatically let prompt message don't display?

Tags: android

I use the following code to forward sms, but a system prompt message displayed, how can set system preference programmatically let prompt message don't display?

[image]

```
private static void ForwardSMS(MSms myMSms, MRule rule) {
    SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
    for (String toAddress : rule.receiverNumberList) {
        smsMgr.sendTextMessage(toAddress, null, myMSms.body, null, null);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(PublicPar.myContext);
        if (prefs.getBoolean("SaveSentBox", true)) {
            SaveToSentBox(toAddress, myMSms.body);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really hope you can't. I'd really like to know if an App I install is about to run up charges on my account.

Comment: This is a sms forward app, so app will show prompt messge when you install app

Comment: Best you can do is prominently state that you pledge to only ever forward messages to user-selected choices, so they can safely check the "remember my choice".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This kind of prompt is for the users' own protection, and the Android API does not allow developers to disable it. So in short: There is no way to do this legitimately.

Answer (score 0):

See, The image you have pasted here is asking the user about giving the permission to the app for sending SMS which may cause him money. Wouldn't you like to be warned in such cases where you can loose your charge because of the App.? So the Android doesn't provide any authority to the developers by which they can harm users credits or charges without even telling them.

But yes, as you can see there are options provided to "Remember the Choice". That means if users is aware of this fact once, and allows the app by clicking "Always Allow", next time there will be no popup to the user before sending the SMS.

So no matter what the app is, the Android API will always be loyal to the user and tell him about the loss me may suffer because of any App.